# Is Deferred Execution in Asp.net MVC View a very bad thing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say i have the following model which is obtained via Entity Framework:

```
public class User{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Get all the users from the user table:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = from u in myDbContext.Users
                          select u;
```

Reder the users in the View (@model IEnumerable):

```
@foreach(var item in Model) 
 {
 <tr>@item.Id</tr>
 <tr>@item.Name</tr>
 }
```

My new boss is telling me that doing it this way is not MVC conform and the performance will be very bad. What i should do is to materalize all USERS in the Controller with .ToList(). I am not sure what is better, because either way the users have to be materialized and i dont see any performance losses.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how many users do you have?

Comment: your linq query will load every single user in the database into memory - is that what you really want? Perhaps you could consider paginating your results, pulling back only 50 or 100 at a time?

Comment: Hi, thx for your note. Yes the results is paged, i just want to simplify the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deferred execution means, your actual SQL query behind the LINQ expression won't be executed until you start accessing the items in the users collection (when you iterate those in the `foreach` loop). That means, There will be a SELECT query executed if you are trying to access a navigational property (and it is a unique record) on the User entity

If you only have a single user table (like what you have showed in your question) without any foreign keys/vanigational properties, With the above code you have, EF will execute only one query to get data from your User table. But typically this is not the case, You might have foreign keys to a lot of different tables from the User table. In that case Entity framework does thing differently.

Let's take an example.

Assume that we have a second table, **UserType** which has 4 columns, `Id`, `Name` ,`Code` and `IsAdmin` and your User table has a third column called `UserTypeId` which has a foreign key to this new `UserType` table. Every user record is associated with a `UserType` record.

Now you want to display all the Users with the UserType name. Let's see different approaches.

### 1. Deferred execution,

You will execute this code to get all the users

```
var users = dbContext.Users;
```

And pass the users to the razor view where you will iterate through the collection.

```
@model IEnumerable<YourEntityNameSpace.User>
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <div>
        @user.Name - @user.UserType.Name
    </div>
}
```

When we execute this page, Entity framework is going to run 1 select query on the User table to get the user records along with the `UserTypeId` and when the foreach block is being executed, it is going to query the `UserType` table for each unique `UserTypeId` from the original result set(`users`). You can see this if you run a SQL profiler.

[image]

You can see that EF is passing `UserTypeId` (2 in my picture). I had 3 different UserTypeId's being used in the User table, so it queried the UserType table 3 times, one for each `UserTypeId`.

**Number of SQL queries executed : 4** (1 for user table + 3 for UserType table)

*I had 3 different records in the **UserType** table and i used all those in my **User** Table.*

### 2. Using Include method when querying data

[Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) keyword is used to achieve eager loading. Eager loading is the process where a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query.

```
var users = dbContext.Users.Include(s=>s.UserType);
```

Here you are telling Entity framework to query from ***UserType*** table along with ***User*** table. Entity framework will produce an INNER JOIN sql query between both the tables and execute it.

[image]

You can see that, It queried all the columns of the ***UserType*** table)

**Number of SQL queries executed** : 1

### A Better solution ?

Usually, It is not a good idea to use the entity classes generated by Entity framework in other layers so much. That makes your code tightly coupled.
I would suggest querying only data(columns) which is needed and map that to a POCO class (A simple DTO) and use that in your views /other layers. You may keep these DTO classes in common project which can be referred in other projects (Your Data Access project and UI project)

```
public class UserDto
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;} 
  public UserTypeDto UserType { set; get; }    
}
public class UserTypeDto
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Our view will be bound to a collection of `UserDto` insted of the User `entity`

```
@model IEnumerable<YourCommonNamespace.User>
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <div> @user.Name - @user.UserType.Name </div>
}
```

And now from your Data access layer, you will be returning a collection of `UserDto` instead of the `User` entity created by Entity framework.

```
var users = dbContext.Users.Select(s => new UserDto
{
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    UserType = new UserTypeDto
    {
        Id = s.UserType.Id,
        Name = s.UserType.Name
    }
});
```

Here, You can see that We are using the `Select` clause to tell EF which columns we really need. EF will execute an ***INNER JOIN***, but with only those columns, we specified

[image]

**Number of SQL queries executed** : 1

The benefit of this approach is, If you ever want to switch your data access implementation from Entity framework to some other technologoy (Pure ADO.NET/ NHibernate) for your own reasons, You will be only updating your GetUsers method, All other layers (your Razor views/ Other Business layer code etc..) don't need an update because they are not using the entities created by entity framework.

If you do a `ToList()`, EF executes the SQL right away and return the result. But instead if you are not doing that, because of deferred execution, It is going to execute the SQL statement(s) when it actually needs the data (ex : You render some property value in your view inside the loop).

Comment: Thx for your effort and the detailed answer.

Comment: But does it meant that i have to map the poco to the the ViewModel again? Because i want to use the data annotation. Until now i am using the POCOs which is part of a domain project and map them back to ViewModels.

Comment: You can move your view model dto classes to a common project which is accessible to both data access project and ui project, and use those on your Linq projection ( select part ) of your data access code.

Answer (score 5):

This *could* lead to performance problems, but it doesn't necessarily always lead to them.

If you pass an `IEnumerable<T>` to the view then the view doesn't necessarily know anything about the backing data source.  There could be an unspoken assumption that the consuming code (the view) will enumerate the collection only once.  *If* the collection is enumerated more than once, it's *possible* that the backing data store would be queried more than once.

Note that this doesn't necessarily mean hitting a database multiple times, but enumerating a collection could come with all sorts of hidden "gotchas".

Passing an `IList<T>` to the view is a little more explicit in this regard.  The semantic difference between the two interfaces is that the `IList<T>` is a complete list, not just a vague enumeration.  It's expected to support being queried and enumerated as many times as necessary without performance loss.  (There's of course no guarantee that the implementing type provides this, but it's expected to.)

It's not really a question of "deferred execution".  The query is going to execute server-side at *very close* to the same time, whether it's in the controller or in the view.  It's not being deferred for very long.  It's just a question of how that enumeration is going to be treated by the consuming code.

> My new boss is telling me that doing it this way is not MVC conform and the performance will be very bad.

Your new boss really should explain things better.  This has nothing to do with MVC and everything to do with `IEnumerable<T>` vs. `IList<T>` and how LINQ is expected to behave.  The same is true in any application which uses those technologies.  The fact that you're passing a model from a controller to a view makes this MVC, nothing more.  And the performance *might* be bad, if you're not aware of why it could be.  However, there is only ever one true way to know about performance... by measuring it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing it's OK for a "quick and dirty" solution. It's easy to do and it works, but it has some drawbacks if you want to do "proper" code:

You are basically doing DB queries from the view, which is definitely not the place if you are doing a layered application. You should do the DB queries in the controllers for simple applications or in application services or even repositories for more structured and complex applications.

Materializing the queries in the view has also problems in exception handling. The DB exceptions won't be thrown in the controller, so you can't handle them in the controller or on action filters.

In terms of performance, I don't see how it can be different. What you should avoid though is to use lazy loading. If your User entity had a dependent entity or collection, EF would fire an extra query for each user, which would really impact the performance. Ideally you should disable lazy loading. If you follow the rule of sending all data to the view (no deferred queries), this also includes loading all dependent entities upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Doing your way at least extends the life of the context with the risks (never certain but) :

- db lock (cross contexts concurrency on db);
- connexion pool failure: the connexion is given back to the pool when the context is disposed
- "context no longer exists" exception in your view
- ...

keep your context scope as short as possible.

by the way, from an mvc point of view, there is no reason for having the same model for view and data access. This is not a performance issue but a separation of concern issue, that is a maintainability issue.