# Linq query for joining tables Mvc Asp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've these tables for an E-Commerce application and I created these tables in SQL and then added ADO.NET and selected Code First. Used MVC default Identity Code First:

```
Users: UserId(PK), FName, LName

Product: ProductId(PK), ProductName, ProductPrice, CategoryId(FK)

Category: CategoryId(PK), CategoryName

Orders: OrderId(PK), OrderTotal, UserId(FK)

OrderDetails: OdId(PK), OrderId(FK), ProductId(FK), Quantity
```

Each product is related to some category. User can place Order and further Order Details is stored in OrderDetails table.

I want to get PRODUCTS based on User previous purchases which I've stored in Order and OrderDetails table.

**Example** If User A purchases a product "Shirt" from category "Clothing", order is stored in Order table and the product Id is stored in OrderDetails table

I've written this just to give you guys an idea (i hope its clear)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string user = User.Identity.GetUserName();
    var q = db.OrderDetails.Where(m => m.Order.Email == user).ToList();
    var query = (from pd in db.Products
                 join od in db.OrderDetails on pd.ProductId equals od.ProductID
                 join oo in db.Orders on od.OrderId equals oo.OrderId

                 where oo.UserId == user
                 select new
                 {   
                     ProductName = pd.Name,
                     ProductPrice = pd.Price, // six value
                 }).ToList();
    return View(query);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the database diagram:

[image]

Comment: This question is no different from your [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959756) where I tried to help you. It's very likely that you don't need a join at all, but without knowing the relationships between your classes, we can't give you a concrete answer.

Comment: @spender Sorry but I gave you a reply there that I can provide the classes. Its just I don't have much time left for this assignment that I'm working on.

Comment: What's the issue with the LINQ query you have written?

Comment: @spender http://s21.postimg.org/qvzspt8p3/Untitled.png picture of database diagram

Comment: No. Not the database diagram. Your code-first classes that shows the relationships you set up *in code*.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz this:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FypStore.Models.Product]'.

Comment: @spender its alot of code, I mean 5 classes. Is there any other way I can show you classes ?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I believe your current error is

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List1[<>f__AnonymousType92[System.String,System.Nul‌​lable1[System.Decimal]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[FypStore.Models.Product]'

Looks like your Index view is bound to  a collection of Product class object like this

```
@model IEnumerable<YourEntityNamespace.Product>
```

But in your index action, from your LINQ join expression, you are doing a projection to an anonymous type with 2 properties, ProductName and ProductPrice.

```
var query = (from pd in db.Products
                 join od in db.OrderDetails on pd.ProductId equals od.ProductID
                 join oo in db.Orders on od.OrderId equals oo.OrderId

                 where oo.UserId == user

                 select new  // Projection to Anonymous type
                 {   
                     ProductName = pd.Name,
                     ProductPrice = pd.Price, // six value
                 }).ToList();
```

To fix your current problem, you can remove the projection and select pd.

```
var query = (from pd in db.Products
                 join od in db.OrderDetails on pd.ProductId equals od.ProductID
                 join oo in db.Orders on od.OrderId equals oo.OrderId

                 where oo.UserId == user                    
                 select pd).ToList();
```

Even though that will fix your current error, That is not the optimal solution. With the above solution, we are passing an entire Products(*after your where filter of course*) entities to the view. These entities might have other navigation properties and accessing them in your razor view in a loop will generate sql queries again.  Read more about the problems with this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33921573/40521).

Your best solution is to create a new viewmodel class/DTO class in a common project which is accessable to your UI project and Data access project(If you have multiple projects), and use that in your LINQ expressions projection and bind your razor view to a collection of your new view model class.

```
public class ProductVM
{
  public string ProductName {set;get;}
  public decimal ProductPrice {set;get;}
}
```

And in your LINQ expression use that in the projection.

```
var products = (from pd in db.Products
             join od in db.OrderDetails on pd.ProductId equals od.ProductID
             join oo in db.Orders on od.OrderId equals oo.OrderId

             where oo.UserId == user
             select new ProductVM
             {   
                 ProductName = pd.Name,
                 ProductPrice = pd.Price, // six value
             }).ToList();
     return View(products);
```

Since we are now returning a list of ProductVM class objects to our view, We should update the razor view to

```
@model List<YourNamespace.ProductVM>
<h1>Products</h1>
@foreach(var p in Model)
{
  <h2>@p.ProductName - @p.ProductPrice </h2>
}
```

**You may add more properties to your view model if you view absolutely need them**

Comment: That actually removed the error but doesn't return any products. Whatever products user has purchased, that product's id is stored in OrderDetails table. I guess first I've to get that product Id, then find the category of that product ("Clothing") and show that user more products from clothing category.

Comment: Put visual studio break points in your code and see you are getting the correct product I'd.  Your query does not look like it is querying from category table. You need to correct the query to get the day you want. Also it is not a good idea to ask a different question in a comment.  Your original question was about your compilation error.