# How to get only the first element with Include()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to get all cars but only the latest report of each car and not all cards and all their reports. One car can have multiple reports.

```
// with this i would get all cars with all reports for each car.
// How can i get all cars with only the last report for each car?
context.Cars.Include("Reports");
```

I tried something like this:

```
context.Cars.Include(c => c.Reports.OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault())
.Take(10)
.ToList();
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that the people who wrote the `Include()` function would consider this optimization to be worth implementing. Use two queries.

Comment: use `.Select(...)` instead

Comment: @GeneR would it be too much to ask for an example? Even an more abstract one would do.

Comment: @GaryMcGill could you show me an example? Because i can't think of a "reasonable" one. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.Select(p => new
{
    Car = p,
    Report = p.Reports.OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
})
```

this will give a list of anonymous objects, which you may transform to `IEnumerable<Cars>`

Comment: While both this answer and @octavioccl's achieve the same result, @octavioccl's is better, as it's explicit about what's happening. Here, the include happens implicitly to satisfy the `Select`, but it's easy to forget or neglect to recognize that. Also, using explicit loading with a filter lets you keep your entity type, without having to cast a set of anonymous objects.

Answer (score 8):

I'm agree with @GaryMcGill, `Include` extension method doesn't let you load partially the navigation property. What you can do is use [Explicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit) instead:

```
var car=yourPreviousQuery.FirstOrDefault(); // This is just an example to have a Car instance
context.Entry(car) 
    .Collection(b => b.Reports) 
    .Query().OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).Take(1) 
    .Load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have  Dto's/Viewmodels like this

```
public class CarDto
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
public class ReportDto
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class CatSimpleDto
{
    public CarDto Car { set; get; }
    public ReportDto FirstPost { set; get; }
}
```

You can do an order by descending on the `Reports` (On Id or Insert timestamp etc)
and take the first item.

```
var carsWithFirstReport= db.Cars.
Select(s => new CatSimpleDto
{
    Car = new CarDto { Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name },
    FirstPost = s.Reports.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id).Take(1)
    .Select(x => new ReportDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name
    }).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Projecting to DTO's /POCO's will eliminate deferred execution ( and hence executing more queries on your db as you access the navigation properties) compared to selecting the entities created by entity framework.  Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921262/is-deferred-execution-in-asp-net-mvc-view-a-very-bad-thing/33921573#33921573).