# How to get specific number of rows when using Include method in entity framwork?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have posts and comments tables. I can get posts and comment by this :

```
            List<Posts> posts = db.Posts.Include("Comments").ToList();
```

The above code return all comments of each post. I want two things :

1. Get 5 comments of each post.
2. Get the total number of comments of each post while getting only 5 comments of each post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a Post DTO/View model/POCO like this

```
public class PostDto
{
    public string Title{ set; get; }
    public int Id { set; get; }  

    public List<PostDto> Comments { set; get; }

    public int TotalCommentCount { set; get; }
}
```

The below will get all Posts and last 5 comments with comment count.
You can update the OrderByDescending to pass another property if you want (like Insert time stamp etc)

```
 var posts = dbContext.Posts.
        Select(s => new PostDto
        {
            Id = s.PostId,
            Title= s.PostTitle,
            TotalCommentCount = s.Comments.Count(),
            Comments = s.Comments.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id).Take(5)
                .Select(x => new PostDto
                {
                    Id = x.CommentId,
                    Name = x.CommentText
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

This will execute only one query against the db. Read [deferred execution and performance here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921262/is-deferred-execution-in-asp-net-mvc-view-a-very-bad-thing/33921573#33921573) for more information

Comment: Similar to Maxim Goncharuk's answer, but projecting to a concrete class, and including the **necessary** ordering to get the latest comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `Include` method to get what you want to achieve.
In the following example the results are returned in an anonymous type:

```
var postInfo = db.Posts.Select(p => new
{
    Post = p,
    Comments = p.Comments.Take(5),
    TotalNumberOfComments = p.Comments.Count
})
```

Comment: Where is teh include? This update answer is exactly like Maxim Goncharuk's. You should have deleted instead of updated your question. besides, you can't do that with include (it always brings all the realted rows, you cannot filter or limit it)

Comment: @JotaBe I don't understand your question. Anyway if you are assuming I have copied it, you should note my answer is 10 minutes older :)

Comment: I don't mind if you copied it or not. The question is that you're not using `Include` anywhere, and you couldn't use it either. I think your original question included something related to `Include` which is no longer there, I suppose since you edited it 5 minutes after Maxim's answer. Don't worry, don't be so eager to get reputation: good answers will bring it to you along the time. SO is great for helping, and learning by answering questions. The rest reputation will come by itself ;) Many times, most reputation comes from the most unexpected answer.

Answer (score 2):

Get 5 comments for each post:

```
var postWithComments = db.Posts.Select(x => new 
  {
    Post = x,
    Comments = x.Comments.Take(5),
    CommentsCount = x.Comments.Count()
  });
```

Method `Take(5)` allows you to load only 5 comments with inner data and method `Count()` gets only count of rows.

Comment: *Entity Framework allows you loading part of data if you don't use `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.* This makes no sense at all. Please, update your explanation: materializing a query has nothing to do with "loading part of the data" at all. Your answer uses *a projection to an anonymous class*.