# How to show different text according to a bool value from the SQL database?

Tags: sql, linq, razor, linq-to-sql

Why in the view page, it shows all the rows "Not active currently" with this following code?

```
          <td>
            @{
                if (item.LeadEngineers.All(n => n.Active == false))
                {
                    @: Not active currently

                }
                var y = item.LeadEngineers.Where(n => n.Active == true).ToList();
                if (y.Count() > 0)
                {

                    @: Currently active
                }
            }

        </td>
```

I want to check if the item's value in another table `LeadEngineers` is `true` or `false`, to show the item is currently active or not.

The item has many records in the table `LeadEngineers`, I want to check if all the records/rows have `Active=False`, then show "not active", if there's one row (at least one) has `Active=true`, then show "active now".

The definition of the `item` is in the view Model `LeadIndexData`:

```
public class LeadIndexData
{
    //to show each item's full name
    public IEnumerable<WebUser> WebUsers { get; set; }

    //to show each item's assigned techniques
    public IEnumerable<Technique> Techniques { get; set; }

    //to show each item's supervised employees
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeTech> EmployeeTechs { get; set; }

    //to show if it's active or not
    public IEnumerable<LeadEngineer> Leads { get; set; }
 }
```

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? techId)
    {
        var viewModel = new LeadIndexData();
        var query = (from b in db.LeadEngineers
                     join a in db.WebUsers
                     on b.User_ID equals a.User_ID
                     where a.Active == true
                     select new
                     {
                         User_ID = b.User_ID,
                         User_FirstName = a.User_FirstName,
                         User_Surname = a.User_Surname
                     }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new WebUser
                     {
                         User_ID = (int)x.User_ID,
                         User_FirstName = x.User_FirstName,
                         User_Surname = x.User_Surname
                     }).Distinct().ToList(); 

        //put the query results into the list of leads
        var engineers = query.AsEnumerable();

        //use HashSet to hold a set of lead webusers
        HashSet<WebUser> vme = new HashSet<WebUser>();

        //access each item in the leads list and assign the lead webuser's details to each
        foreach (var wu in engineers)
        {
            var w = new WebUser { User_ID = wu.User_ID, User_Surname = wu.User_FullName };
            if (!(vme.Any(x => x.User_ID == wu.User_ID)))
            {
                vme.Add(w); //add the lead webuser details to the hashSet
            }
        }
        //put the webusers details vme in the leadengineer viewmodel
        viewModel.WebUsers = vme.ToList();
        .....
      }
```

My Index View page:

```
     @model Version0.Models.LeadIndexData
    ....
    ....
     @foreach (var item in Model.WebUsers)
    {
    string selectedRow = "";
    if (item.User_ID == ViewBag.userId)
    {
        selectedRow = "success";
    }
    <tr class="@selectedRow" valign="top">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_Surname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{

                if (item.LeadEngineers.Any(n => n.Active == true))
                {
                    @: Currently active
                }
                else
                {
                    @: Not active currently
                }
            }

        </td>
            ....
      </table>
```

Comment: Please show the code of the Controller populating the model, please...

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
  <td>
        @{
            if (item.LeadEngineers.Any(n => n.Active == true))
            {
                @: Currently active
            }
            else
            {
                @: Not active currently
            }
        }
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried with that, but it still shows "Not active currently" for all the items in the list, why? when I debug, it shows item.LeadEngineers Count=0  why it's 0? The item has its ID, but why its count in LeadEngineers table is 0?

Comment: Show definition of item

Comment: Are you including the LeadEngineers property in your item when querying ? Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921262/is-deferred-execution-in-asp-net-mvc-view-a-very-bad-thing/33921573#33921573) about deferred execution.

Comment: @claire i mean how you fill it with data. Code looks fine. Problem either in data or it the way how you fill it.