# Should I use ViewBag to pass a list to a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Not sure why I got down voted but I'm going to re-write my question after doing some research and testing. This is a side project that I'm using to learn MVC/EF/Repository/Bootstrap etc. I only get a couple hours here a few nights a week to work on it.

**Basic original question:**

I know I should really be using a List<> in a ViewModel to pass the data to the View but I'm not sure how or if it will meet my requirement.

What I am trying to do is get a list of users to display in a table which would have a checkbox in each row. Above that table I want to have a list of Groups to that they could be assigned to. You select the section from the DropDownList (DDL) and then check who you want to assign it to. It's the groups/sections that I want want to assign as a list and pass to the View.

So, I've got a ViewModel with a list and I'm using a repository to populate the VM. What I don't know how to do exactly is where/when to populate that list with each VM object and even if I do and there are say 50 users I wouldn't want to make 50 trips to the DB to pull the same information.That is why I'm thinking that for this scenario using the ViewBag to pass that Group list to the View might be justifiable. On the flip side I would like to learn how to populate that list properly in the VM for future coding.

**Updated question/code:**

So, after more research and following some suggestions I've now got the following code. I'm still not sure how I will properly populate my Patrols in my ViewModel in order to populate the DDL in my View.

At the moment I've got the View displaying the table with the checkboxes. Now I'm back to working on getting the values to populate the DDL and then I'll have to work on posting to the controller, looping to find the check rows, and updating the database. In my case each member record is defaulted to a PatrolId=0 and this page should allow me to update the PatrolId to a value from the DDL.

The Patrols property in the PatrolMemberViewModel should be a list of about 5 records that I would pull from a DB table instead of hard coding in the DDL.

ViewModel:

```
 public class PatrolViewModel
    {
        public int PatrolId { get; set; }
        public string PatrolName { get; set; }
    }

    public class PatrolMemberViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public int PatrolId { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string PhonePrimary { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string EmailPrimary { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        public PatrolViewModel Patrols { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResult Unassigned()
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<PatrolMemberViewModel> model = repository.SelectAllUnassigned();
                return View(model);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error retrieving the record.");
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Repository:

```
public IEnumerable<PatrolMemberViewModel> SelectAllUnassigned()
        {
            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                var results = (from p in db.Person
                               where p.IsActive == true
                               && p.IsScout == true
                               && p.PatrolId == 0
                               select new PatrolMemberViewModel
                               {
                                   MemberId = p.PID,
                                   FirstName = p.FirstName ?? string.Empty,
                                   LastName = p.LastName ?? string.Empty,
                                   EmailPrimary = p.EmailPrimary ?? string.Empty,
                                   PhonePrimary = p.PhonePrimary ?? string.Empty,
                                   PatrolId = p.PatrolId,
                                   IsSelected = false
                               }
                                ).OrderBy(o => o.LastName).ThenBy(o => o.FirstName).ToList();

                return results;
            }
        }
```

View:

```
@model IList<ProjectName.ViewModels.PatrolMemberViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Unassigned";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Patrols</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Patrol", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed tbackground">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">

            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                First Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Email
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Phone
            </th>
        </tr>


        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:@Model[i].EmailPrimary">@Model[i].EmailPrimary</a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PhonePrimary)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    </table>

    <div class="control-wrapper">
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Assign" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Making 50 calls to the db has nothing to do with ViewBag vs ViewModel solutions. It is about how you are querying.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921262/is-deferred-execution-in-asp-net-mvc-view-a-very-bad-thing/33921573#33921573

Comment: @Shyju...can you take a look at my Update I posted in my question and see you can tell what I'm doing wrong? Thanks...

Comment: Its a bit hard to correlate your _list of users_ and _list of Groups_ to the code you have shown (how does that relate to `MemberSectionViewModel` and `Sections` and `PatrolViewModel` and `MemberPatrolViewModel`)?

Comment: And are your wanting to use checkboxes to make selections, then you view model should have a property `bool IsSelected` for strong binding.

Comment: But are you wanting to select a group and then check the users for the group and submit the form, or are you wanting to be able to edit the users for all groups and one time and post everything back in one go (it makes a big difference as to how the view models and UI need to be designed).

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to have a DDL above a list of unassigned users. The Admin will pick which group from the DDL and then use the check box on the users to select which ones to assign. This would be in a Form so I can submit it and update the database.

Comment: @Caverman You need to edit you question to make it clear what your wanting to do (and make the models relate to your question). Then an answer can be added showing how to do this.

Comment: Your question is still not clear and I have interpreted this 2 ways. First is that you want to display a list of all members that do not have a `PatrolId` assigned to them (and assign one), in which case your UI would display the detail of each member with an associated dropdownlist to select a `Patrol`.

Comment: Second is that you want to have  single dropdownlist to select a `Patrol` and a list of all users. When you select a `Patrol`, the associated checkboxes are update to show which users have been assigned that `Patrol` and you can edit the checkboxes to add/remove users who are associated with that `Patrol`. Both are easy enough to do.

Comment: More like your first interpretation. This is where an Admin will go view all unassigned members. The are determined to be unassigned because PatrolId=0. When the unassigned.cshtml opens I'm going to have a DDL at the top with all available patrols and then a table with checkboxes of all the unassigned. The Admin would select the Patrol from the DDL and then select all the members to assign to it. After that selection there will be a button to Assign at the bottom, I would loop through, get those that are checked and update the table with the PatrolId. At least that's the idea for now.

Comment: @Caverman I added an answer but not sure if I misunderstood your last comment and I based my answer on the second option (which was what your question and comment is suggesting). My _first interpretation_ was to have a list of the members and a dropdownlist for each member to select their `Patrol` which is the better UI I think (it means you can assign a `Patrol` to every member in one hit). If you do want an answer for that option, let me know and I can add a second one (but start the message as per this one so I am notified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating the view models to represent what you want to display/edit in the view. Your `PatrolMemberViewModel` can be used but remove the `[Key]` attribute and the `int PatrolId` and `PatrolViewModel Patrols` properties.

Then create the parent view model

```
public class AssignPatrolViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Patrol")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a patrol")]
    public int? SelectedPatrol { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PatrolList { get; set; }
    public List<PatrolMemberViewModel> Members { get; set; }
}
```

and you GET method would be

```
public ViewResult Unassigned()
{
  var model = new AssignPatrolViewModel
  {
      PatrolList = new SelectList(db.Patrols, "PatrolId", "PatrolName"), // modify to suit
      Members = repository.SelectAllUnassigned().ToList()
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model AssignPatrolViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedPatrol)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPatrol, Model.PatrolList, "Please select")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedPatrol)
    <table>
        .... // thead elements
        <tbody>
            @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Members.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Members[i].IsSelected)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Members[i].MemberId)
                        // add other hidden inputs for properties you want to post
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Members[i].FirstName)</td>
                    ....
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Assign" class="btn btn-success" />
}
```

Then in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Unassigned(AssignPatrolViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.PatrolList = new SelectList(db.Patrols, "PatrolId", "PatrolName");
        return View(model);
    }
    // Get selected ID's
    IEnumerable<int> selected = model.Members.Where(m => m.IsSelected).Select(m => m.MemberId);
    // Get matching data models
    var members = db.Person.Where(p => selected.Contains(p.PID)); // modify to suit
    // loop each each member, update its PatrolId to the value of model.SelectedPatrol
    // save and redirect
}
```

Comment: Big THANKS for taking the time to write this up. I have been working on this off and on over the last few days and go close to what you had but this defiantly helped fill in the gaps and got it to work. I haven't done the POST yet but that's next and I'll use your example.

Comment: I had a little time to start working on the POST piece of this. Using your sample I was able to get the selected members and their objects but I don't understand how I would get the selected PatrolId from the dropdownlist. I'll try to search that piece as well and see what I can come up with.

Comment: The selected `PatrolID` value is in `model.SelectedPatrol` (see the comments at end of last code snippet. So for example, you could use `foreach(var member in members) { member.PatrolID = model.SelectedPatrol; ..... };`

Comment: @Stephen...I wanted to say Thanks again. Looks like I was able to get it to work using your code example and not it's starting to click in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class for your view model, with the list of users and the list of sections as properties within it. Some people seem to like that approach.

But I think your use of ViewBag for passing the list of sections is perfectly valid. I do that all the time for DDLs like this.