# How to perform a join in c# .net core Entity Framework using

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this relation ship.

[image]

In both of this model I have a navigation properties, however I still don't know how to use them.

The Customer Model

```
 public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]     
    public int CustomerGroupId { get; set; }
    public CustomerGroup CustomerGroup { get; set; }

}
```

Customer Group Model

```
public class CustomerGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display a list of customers along with their customer group name.

I have this query but its only giving the customer groups list but not the customers.

[image]

Changes to new query executing.

[image]

what im getting as a return
[image]

The CustomerGroup is null.

Comment: Your question/tags are confusing, can you please clarify it for the sake of others who come across it? Is the question about Entity Framework **Core** or Entity Framework on .NET Core (which shouldn't be possible to run anyways, since EF doesn't run on .NET Core/.NET Standard). Also [tag:asp.net-mvc] is for the legacy ASP.NET MVC 1-5, not for ASP.NET Core, there it's [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]. May also be useful: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and why you should avoid stuffing tags into the question (C#, .NET Core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both groups and their customers, you need to tell EF to include the navigation property:

```
db.CustomerGroups.Include(g => g.Customers).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Been searching for this solution for hours. Thank you @slaks.

Answer (score 2):

Get all customers and in the view, when you loop through the list of customers , simply access the `CustomerGroup` navigational property of each item.

```
var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
return View(customers);
```

and in the view

```
@model List<Customer>
@foreach(var c in Model)
{
  <p>@c.FirstName </p>
  <p>@c.CustomerGroup.Name</p>
}
```

Make sure your `CustomerGroup` property is `virtual`

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]     
    public int CustomerGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerGroup CustomerGroup { get; set; }    
}
```

Keep in mind that this will do lazy loading. To do eager loading (a single query to get everything), you may consider using a view model and project to that.

So create a view model

```
public class CustomerVm
{
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  public string GroupName { set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action project your LINQ query result to a collection of this view model.

```
 var customerVms = db.Customers
                    .Select(x=> new CustomerVm { FirstName = x.Name, 
                                                 GroupName =x.CustomerGroup.Name})
                    .ToList();
 return View(customerVms );
```

Make sure your view is now strongly typed to a list of CustomerVm's.

```
@model List<CustomerVm>
@foreach(var c in Model)
{
  <p>@c.FirstName </p>
  <p>@c.GroupName</p>
}
```

Add other properties to your view model **as needed** by the view.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921262/is-deferred-execution-in-asp-net-mvc-view-a-very-bad-thing/33921573#33921573) for understanding the difference between eager loading vs lazy loading

Comment: If I do var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
return View(customers); I get  "NullReferenceException". I don't want to do a view model. I just want to simple do a join using my navigatioins. ToList() looks good but only return values of the customers the customer groups is null.

Comment: With the entity class definition you provided, EF will generate table with `CustomerGroupId` column as **not null**.  With that, every customer should have a customer group id stored with it. Where are you getting null reference exception ? Is `db` initialized (not null) ?

Comment: I edit my post so you can see the query executing(basically the one you gave me) and what im getting in return.

Comment: For EF, to properly lazy load stuff. your `CustomerGroup` property should be `virtual`. See the updated answer.